# Find is the regular expression with start and end character

Tags: java

In this expression I want to extract string  that starts with href= till it finds the closing bracket ]. I want to find string start with href= till closing bracket for the whole expression. How do I do that

```
  String s=  [a href="http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/
    2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4.jpg"][a href="https://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd-copy.jpg"]

The output should be
"http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/
    2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4.jpg"
"https://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd-copy.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this : `(?<=\[a href=)(.*?)\]`

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/sN3tZ5/1)

PS : In the demo, check the *match information* on the RHS to know what has been matched.

Explanation :

`(?<=\[a href=)(.*?)\]`
`?<=` is positive look-behind, i.e, the contents will be matched only if they are preceeded by `[a href=`.

Next, we have to escape `[` because they have special meaning in regex. The same applies to `]`.

Also, we should not include the `]` in the output, so we use `(.*?)\]` to capture everything after `[a herf=` and before `]`.

The `?` quantifier after `.*` makes it `lazy` (non-greedy) so that it matches the first `]` rather than the last `]`.

Comment: Can u please explain what does it mean New to Regular expression

Comment: Pattern GetCddata = Pattern.compile("(?<=\[a href=)(.*?)\]"); It say invalid escape sequences \b \t \n \f \r \' \" \\

Comment: @RameshRaju - In java , you need to use 2 slashes to escape. Also, you need to use Pattern and Matcher classes and group(1) in matcher.

Comment: How do I convert the (?<=[a href=)(.*?)] to javascript I tried but not able to